# My object is too transparent, how to fix it?

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor

I'm following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF6qkByl-_M and around 29:25, he copies his material nodes from the grass to his leaves and mine turned out to be too transparent.

[image]

Here are my nodes for the grass:[image]

If you need anymore information here's my .blend file: [image]

Comment: does your texture have an alpha channel(is it png/tiff/etc) ? you are connecting it wrong.. the alpha should be used as a factor in mix shader , not color

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so all I had to was move the Alpha output and move it to the third mix shader from the right like-so.[image]

Thanks root.